# Validation rule field mandatory only for unique profile

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I need a specific case (here: Queue) owner to fill a field when the case is reassigned back to another owner.

In other words: We get a case via email. We fill out the necessary fields and then transfer the case to a developer queue. These developers don't take over ownership but rather work inside the queue. After the solution they have to fill out a specific field before they can reassign the case back to the service rep.

My VR so far:

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(Errorresolution_Firefighter__c)),
$Profile.Id = "XYZ"
)
```

But nothing happens no matter who get´s the case.
What did I wrong?

Kind regards.
Alex

Comment: You need to remove the `NOT` function from the field check,(assuming `Profile.Id` is that of the developer user.) In VR , you need to specify the error condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need the `Validation rule` to fire when developer users are assigning the Case back to service rep.

We specify error condition in validation rule.
Below 2 conditions needs to be met for firing validation rule :

1. `Errorresolution_Firefighter__c` field is blank
2. Owner of Case is queue just before changing the owner back to service reps.

We just need to remove `NOT` function & add prior value check for `ownerId` same as that of `queue` from the rule as below :

```
AND(
  ISBLANK(Errorresolution_Firefighter__c),
  PRIORVALUE( OwnerId ) = 'queue-id'
)
```

Also check - [Cross-Object owner fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option)

Comment: Thanks so far for the time and patience. Unfortunately nothing changed after I alter the VR. I still can switch ownership with the empty field. Also when login in as a "normal" user.

Comment: ok , so your requirement is to prevent ownership change irrespective of the user who is the current owner?

Comment: @AlexM.: I understood the flaw in the solution. I've updated my answer with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks again. No, the ownership itself should be no problem. But once the developer queue got the case/ownership whatever they do with the case the specific field need to be filed out.
I did a simple test and only made the field not blank without any modifications. Turns out nothing happens at all. So I need to dig somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, so with this it works everytime: NOT(ISBLANK( Errorresolution_Firefighter__c)),
Unfortunately also when I try to change the ownership to the dev queue.
But I need the other way around. Everyone can assign it to the devs but THEY need to fill it out before they can reassign it.

Comment: @AlexM. : Did you try the condition from the answer? It checks if the prior owner is queue and then field condition is checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146350/discussion-between-rohit-and-alex-m).

Answer (score 1):

Validation Rule:

```
  AND(

     LEN(Errorresolution_Firefighter__c) = 0,

     ISCHANGED(OwnerId),

     PRIORVALUE(OwnerId)='ownerId',

     NOT($Profile.Name='Profile Name')
)
```

Note: change owner Id and Profile name as per your org.

> Rich text fields are a little wonky. ISNULL and ISBLANK don't work
> with this field type, period.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385791&type=1